# Jquery Class Selector Fails to Select new Class Instances Added with .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I'm semi-new to Javascript/jQuery so apologies in advanced if I'm missing something basic. I have a function that is triggered whenever a user types in an element with a specific class.

```
     $('.relevantClass').keyup(function(){
     //code...
     });
```

Now this function may end up, depending on the situation, creating a good deal of new HTML including new instances of `relevantClass` through the `.append()` method.

```
     var newHTML = <div class='relevantclass'>Content...</div>;
     $('#wrapper').append(newHtml);
```

However, the jQuery selector does not seem to detect and execute the function when a user types in the newly created `relevantClasses`. I've checked the newly created Html and it has the correct class tags and old instances of the relevant class due work.

I'm guessing this has something to do with `.append();` messing with the DOM and I need someway to "refresh" the selector and let it do its jQuery thing researching the DOM to find the new classes. Any thoughts on how to do this? Is there some jQuery method I can't find?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `on()` to attach events that work on dynamic content:

```
var $parent = $("selector"); //the element you're appending .relevantClass to
$parent.on("keyup",".relevantClass",function(){
    //code...
});
```

Keep in mind that to work with dynamic content, you have to attach the event to `relevantClass`'s closest parent that exists on page load.

Some people use `body`, but you should get used to using parent elements as close as you can get to the dynamic content. This is so that event delegation occurs on a smaller scale.

More info on `on()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Also, I hope that `newhtml` variable is wrapped in quotes.

Comment: Great, thanks! Looks like this is exactly what I need. I'll let everyone know tomorrow when I can get back to this if it works.

newHtml is actually some godawful 200 char string of about three nested divs with lots of variables that I have to use .replace and regex to format dynamically. Then it gets passed to .append. Just wanted to spare you all the awfulness of it.

Comment: @purmou While I agree it's a good habit to use the closest parent for the delegated event handler, you should probably make that clearer in your code as well; if `.relevantClass` doesn't exist yet, `.parent()` doesn't find anything and the handler never gets bound. It works in this case because there are existing `.relevantClass` elements and the code just appends more, but in general you should hard-code a direct selector for the parent based on the html. (+1 anyway)

Comment: @nbrooks: Excellent catch, I didn't even realize that issue. I'll make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.relevantClass').on('keyup', function(){
    //code...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$('body').on('keyup', '.relevantClass', function() { ... }
```

The idea is that you use an existing root element and use your class selector as a filter. See the examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).